# Unable to add jQuery js files in already added UI jQuery files

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins

I have added some jQuery js files in my project. Now I want to add titlecase js file but this JS needs jquery.js file also. When I add this jquery.js file in project then all tabs, accordion etc goes away because of adding jquery.js. How can I do this?

```
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery1.js"></script>  
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/to-title-case.js"></script>
```

When I use only above two then titlecase function works perfectly but when I add some more like below then does not work.

```
       <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.4.4.min.js"></script>
       <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-ui-1.8.9.custom.min.js"></script>
       <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.validate.js"></script>
       <script type="text/javascript" src="js/to-title-case.js"></script>
```

I might be that titlecase file requires jQuery. But when I add jQuery in above script then my all tabs, the accordion goes away.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps it is a problem with the order you're including the Javascript files? I think you need to include jquery.js first, the jquery-ui.js next and then the titlecase.js.

```
<script src="javascript/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="javascript/jquery-ui.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="javascript/titlecase.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```